# Undefined Index error when attempting to setup:static-content:deploy. How to fix?

Tags: magento2, css, index, static-content

[image: Error received when trying to deploy static-content]

**What am I attempting to do here?:**
In the console I kept getting a message that says 404: unable to find styles-m.css.
It finds styles-l.css and print.css but not mobile, no matter what I do.

Google searches told me that I need to do deploy static content to get this working properly (I don't get why but ok). So upon doing this, I get the following messages shown in the image.

So essentially, I don't care much for the deploy static content part, I just want to fix the styles-m so that I don't get the error message. However, if this error message I just got about the index will come to bite me later on, I'd like to fix this as well.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Static deploy is not work after di compile. So delete var/di, run static deplay and then run compiler